# Pessoal Gostaria de saber como Trocar dados entre duas JFRAME

Tags: java, netbeans, jframe

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Passi 1 = Selecionei e mandei o item table: Que é um outro Jframe**

```
private void jTableProduto2MouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                            
        Produto produto = new Produto();
        Home home = new Home();
        if (evt.getClickCount() == 2) {

            TableModelCliente tm = (TableModelCliente) jTableProduto2.getModel();
            cliente= tm.getRowValue(jTableProduto2.getRowSorter().convertRowIndexToModel(jTableProduto2.getSelectedRow()));
            home.addProduto(produto);
            this.dispose();
    }
```

**Passo 2 Tentei receber no Home(que é minha tela controle de caixa)**

```
public void addProduto(Produto produto){

       ftfProdutoIV.setText(produto.getNome());
       ftfValorUnitarioIV.setText(produto.getpVenda());
     ftfCodigoIV.setText(produto.getCodigo());

}
```

tentei setar o valor do meu objeto no TextField, mas por ser uma função Public ele n exibe na tela. 
obs: os dados do objeto chegam no public void addProduto(Produto produto).
se alguem puder me ajudar :) obrigado desde já!

Answer (score 0):

Aparentemente, você está adicionando um **cliente** em vez de um **produto**:

```
TableModelCliente tm = (TableModelCliente) jTableProduto2.getModel();
cliente = tm.getRowValue(jTableProduto2.getRowSorter().convertRowIndexToModel(jTableProduto2.getSelectedRow()));
home.addCliente(cliente);
this.dispose();
```

Nesse trecho de código que colocaste, a função `addProduto` não é chamada.

Comment: A sim, obrigado por avisar... eu apenas errei na hora de colocar o exemplo aqui. agora editei ali, esse é o meu problema real, ele não exibe os dados na tela.